# Laravel: Looping through dynamic route parameter in blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I want to loop through named route with additional parameter, a series of IDs in this case, in the blade template. I have highlighted the line where I want to do this in the code with stars. My purpose is to access the next page when the 'next' button is clicked. The next page looks exactly like the page before, except for a different question card. At present, the page doesn't change on click of the button.

This is the defined route:

```
Route::get('/quiz/{id}', [QuestionController::class, 'show'])->name("question.show");
```

and this is the html blade template to generate the view.

```
`@foreach ($questions as $question) 

                
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-2 offset-md-3">

               


                    <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 border bg-warning rounded border">
                    
                        <h5 class="card-header"> {{ $question->category }} </h5> 
                    
                        <div class="card-body">
                            
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ $question->text }}</h6>
                        
                            @foreach($question->options as $option)
                                <br>
                                <input  type='radio' name="{{ $question->id }}" value="{{ $option->id }}">     
                                 {{ $option->text}} <br>
                            @endforeach
                            
                        </div>
                         
                        **<a href = "{{route('question.show',['id' => $question])}}" class="btn btn-light btn-sm offset-2 offset-md-10" role="button">
                            Next**
                        </a>
                        
                    </div>
                
              

                </div>
        
            @endforeach`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an index with your foreach loop.

Change this: `@foreach ($questions as $question)`

to this: `@foreach ($questions as $index=>$question)`

Then in your anchor tag do something like this:

```
<a href="{{route('question.show',['id' => $questions[$index + 1]])}}" 
   class="btn btn-light btn-sm offset-2 offset-md-10" role="button">
```

Make sure to surround the button with an if statement to catch the last question.

`@if( $index + 1 < count($questions) )`

edit: missing bracket

Comment: Thanks @dengsauve. It throws an error: "Undefined offset: 1 "

Comment: Did you use the if condition?

Comment: Yes, when I used the if condition, the 'next button disappeared.

Comment: @ShreyaAgarwal do you get the "Undefined offset: 1" when clicking the next button?

Comment: yes. then I added the if condition around the button, and that made the 'next' button disappear.

Comment: Is the if condition make ALL the next buttons disappear, or just the last one?

Comment: @ShreyaAgarwal please note that if you copy pasted my answer, I was missing a close bracket. My bad.

Comment: I had fixed the missing bracket. But, it still removes the next button from the page. :(